# PendingIntent for TaskStackBuilder

Tags: android, notifications

I read the document for creating the notification. In that they have used `TaskStackBuilder`:

1. to create seperate task for Activity.
2. to add the parent of activity using addParentStack()
3. to add an intent
4. Eventually to create PendingIntent.

after that they didn't use `StackBuilder` Object to set in `NotificationCompat.Builder` object. They have used `PendingIntent` object.

**Are all of the above informations (to create a seperate task, to identify the parent activity, to identify the intent) reside in PendingInent ?**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use notifications in your app what happens is. You first specify an explicit intent(Normal intent). Then you create **TaskStackBuilder** object to access the activity you wan't to start when notification gets clicked then initialize **PendingIntent** reference with **TaskStackBuilder** **getPendingIntent**() and passes it to notification object.

Now what the **PendingIntent** do is get the intent from the **TaskStackBuilder** object using **stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(int id, Flag)** and passes pending object to notification object by calling **notification.setContentIntent(PendingIntent object)**

To recover mistakes in your code follow this:-

1. First you should create **explict Intent**
2. Then create **TaskStackBuilder** object then add the **parentStack** and **nextIntent**.
3. Create **PendingIntent** object then get it's intent using **stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(int id, Flag)**.
4. Then pass it to Notification object using **notification.setContentIntent(PendingIntent)**.

I am sure you will be done with this instruction...

**Note:-** Notification object does not accept **Intent Object** it requires **PendingIntent object**.